# How to implement an obfuscated password login

Tags: asp.net, security, encryption, cryptography, passwords

Similar to banks, how would you implement a login page where the user has to enter the 3rd, 6th, and 9th letter of the password and if they are correct they can login.

Now this I can see is easy done if everything was plan text, however how would this be done with a one way encrypted password in the db. Id rather not have to decrypt it again.

How would this be done? How do banks do it?

Thanks

Comment: In my opinion, this is a dark path you should not go down. See this post: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7467/how-secure-is-asking-for-specific-characters-of-passwords-instead-of-the-entire

Comment: I'd say it's not possible (or needs a brute-force with partial information) if you're using hashed passwords.

Comment: I think the general answer seems to be that we wouldn't. I don't know if that counts as an answer though. You could store a few combinations by hashing them, but that would constitute a vulnerability in itself, and there may be too many combinations anyway to make this feasible. Yuck.

Comment: I had the same feelings as you guys. So why the hell do banks use it...pfftt.. Thanks for your input guys.

Comment: banks usually use a combination of password and the mechanism you described above, so its not a substitute for a password